# odbtp compiling error centos 7

Tags: php, centos7

I'm getting this php.h **no such file or directory error**

Change to the directory php/ext.
**Open the file Makefile in an editor, such as vi, and change the value of PHP_INCROOT, if necessary.** <--- what value? I use Centos 7

```
gcc -O2 -fpic -DHAVE_ODBTP -DCOMPILE_DL_ODBTP -I/usr/local/php/include/php -I/usr/local/php/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/php/include/php/Zend -I../.. -I./odbtp -o php_odbtp.o -c odbtp/php_odbtp.c
odbtp/php_odbtp.c:29:17: fatal error: php.h: No such file or directory
 #include "php.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_odbtp.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Installed Zend Framework, php_devel